# php session variable updated by select box to show/hide div's of different languages

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu, session-variables

Firstly, apologies for the simplicity of the question but it is beyond my level of skill, i have done my research and i cannot stare at it any longer.

I am building a site that needs to be available in 3 different languages (English, Spanish and Portuguese) and these are selected by a Select input on a right side bar. I have a js function showing/hiding the relevant divs onchange, but the session variable disappears when i leave the page. I am also unsure how to get the saved shown/hidden divs to maintain state when i change pages. All pages use a header template which calls session_start()

Select box code:

```
<div id="languageSelect">
<?php
$_SESSION['language'] = $_POST['languageDropdown'];
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
    <select name="languageDropdown" id="languageDropdown" class="languageDropdown" onchange="selectLanguage();submit();">
        <option name="English" value="English" <?php if (($_SESSION['language'] == '') || ($_SESSION['language'] == 'English')) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>English</option>
        <option name="Español" value="Español" <?php if ($_SESSION['language'] == 'Español') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Español</option>
        <option name="Português" value="Português" <?php if ($_SESSION['language'] == 'Português') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Português</option>
    </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

Javascript code snippet (successfully changes language on the current page)

```
    function selectLanguage() {
if (document.getElementById('languageDropdown').selectedIndex == 0){
    $('#nav-en').show();
    $('#content-en').show();
    $('#nav-es').hide();
    $('#content-es').hide();
    $('#nav-pt').hide();
    $('#content-pt').hide();
}
```

The way I have attempted to solve my problem is by getting the select box to maintain their option when the session variable is submitted () then have the javascript function read which option is still selected on page load and show/hide the relevant div's but no such luck yet.

```
$(function(){

if (document.getElementById('languageDropdown').selectedIndex == 0){
    $('#nav-en').show();
    $('#content-en').show();
    $('#nav-es').hide();
    $('#content-es').hide();
    $('#nav-pt').hide();
    $('#content-pt').hide();
}
if (document.getElementById('languageDropdown').selectedIndex == 1){
    $('#nav-en').hide();
    $('#content-en').hide();
    $('#nav-es').show();
    $('#content-es').show();
    $('#nav-pt').hide();
    $('#content-pt').hide();
}
if (document.getElementById('languageDropdown').selectedIndex == 2){
    $('#nav-en').hide();
    $('#content-en').hide();
    $('#nav-es').hide();
    $('#content-es').hide();
    $('#nav-pt').show();
    $('#content-pt').show();
}
});
```

I am fairly new to php but i have done my research so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "session variable disappears"? `$_SESSION['language'] = $_POST['languageDropdown']` - maybe this line evaluates when it's not a post request and sets session variable to null?

Comment: @vbo Sorry for the vagueness there. I have an echo on a few pages that I am using to test the session variable.  <?php echo "The Language is: " . $_SESSION['language']; ?> It will display "The Language is: English" until I change pages. At which point it reverts to "The Language is: "

Comment: OK. And what about session variable assignment? Looks like it must be surrounded by `if ($_POST)`.

Comment: @vbo Can you elaborate on this please? do you mean if ($_POST) {$_SESSION['language'] = $_POST['languageDropdown'];} ?

Comment: Yes. There is only one place in your code when you change session var. Anyway try to debug when it gets called and what value gets assigned.

Answer (score 1):

You could create another script `update-language.php` with the following code:

```
<?php 

session_start();
$_SESSION['language'] = $_GET['languageDropdown'];

?>
```

Then, in your javascript (using jQuery which it looks like you're partially using), you could write:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#languageDropdown").change(function(){
        $.get("update-language.php",{languageDropdown:$(this).val()});
    });
});
```

This won't reload the page as you're trying to do, but it will load the new script which will update the session variable so that when the page reloads it will recognise the newly selected language.

The [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) command in jQuery will load the script over AJAX so that you don't need the page to refresh.

Here's the full code that I have tested it with:

**index.php**

```
<?php session_start(); 
if($_SESSION['language'] == '') $_SESSION['language'] = "English";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Change Language</title>
    </head>
    <body>

            <div id="languageSelect">
                <p>Your current language is:
                    <select name="languageDropdown" id="languageDropdown" class="languageDropdown">
                <option name="English" value="English" <?php if ($_SESSION['language'] == 'English') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>English</option>
                <option name="Español" value="Español" <?php if ($_SESSION['language'] == 'Español') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Español</option>
                <option name="Português" value="Português" <?php if ($_SESSION['language'] == 'Português') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Português</option>
                  </select>
                </p>
            </div>

            <nav id="nav-en" <?php if ($_SESSION['language'] != 'English') echo 'style="display:none"'; ?>><a href="#link">English Navigation</a></nav>
            <nav id="nav-es" <?php if ($_SESSION['language'] != 'Español') echo 'style="display:none"'; ?>><a href="#link">Español Navigation</a></nav>
            <nav id="nav-pt" <?php if ($_SESSION['language'] != 'Português') echo 'style="display:none"'; ?>><a href="#link">Português Navigation</a></nav>

            <section id="content-en" <?php if ($_SESSION['language'] != 'English') echo 'style="display:none"'; ?>>
                <h1>English Content</h1>
            </section>
            <section id="content-es" <?php if ($_SESSION['language'] != 'Español') echo 'style="display:none"'; ?>>
                <h1>Español Content</h1>
            </section>
            <section id="content-pt" <?php if ($_SESSION['language'] != 'Português') echo 'style="display:none"'; ?>>
                <h1>Português Content</h1>
            </section>

            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(function($){

        $("#languageDropdown").change(function(){

            //update the language session
            $.get("update-language.php",{languageDropdown:$(this).val()});

            //change the current interface language
            $("#content-en, #content-es, #content-pt, #nav-en, #nav-es, #nav-pt").hide();
            if($(this).val() == "English")
                $("#content-en, #nav-en").show();
            else if($(this).val() == "Español")
                $("#content-es, #nav-es").show();
            else if($(this).val() == "Português")
                $("#content-pt, #nav-pt").show();

        });

      });
      </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**update-language.php**

```
<?php 

session_start();
$_SESSION['language'] = $_GET['languageDropdown'];

?>
```

There are simpler ways to build a small language system like this, but that's another discussion altogether. Hopefully this solution suits your needs and the code you already have.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have implemented your solution but the echo shows no session variable. I have absolutely no experience with Ajax. I am happy to implement this in the simplest way possible, as the site will be very unlikely to grow in its complexity. I just need to get the session variable to maintain its value between pages then i can figure it out from there.

Comment: Sorry you weren't able to get the initial answer working. I've provided some full (working) code that should do the trick in the edited answer above, in light of my suggestion.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort Scott. I was able to implement a messy solution without ajax but I am definitely going to get this working. Much appreciated